# Return an Array of Object and Function Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

**First of all, the problem I'm facing:**

I worked a few months with a self made React Hook with vanilla JS, code bellow:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const useForm = (initialValues) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialValues);

    return [
        state,
        (e) => {
            if (typeof e.target !== 'undefined') {
                setState({
                    ...state,
                    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
                });
            } else {
                setState({ ...e });
            }
        },
    ];
};

export default useForm;
```

Right now, I decided to go Typescript. However could not convert that hook. I got like everything in place but the return interface/type. Same hook Typescript version (with a wrong return type):

```
import { useState, FormEvent } from 'react';

interface ReturnProps {
  [index: number]: Record<string, unknown>;
  [index: number]: (e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
}

const useForm = (initialValues: Record<string, unknown>): ReturnProps => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialValues);

  return [
    state,
    (e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
      if (typeof e.currentTarget !== 'undefined') {
        setState({
          ...state,
          [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value,
        });
      } else {
        setState({ ...e });
      }
    },
  ];
};

export default useForm;
```

**Question is**: How to return the right type in this situation?

Comment: `type ReturnProps = [
  Record<string, unknown>,
  (e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void,
];`

Now that's right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to fix the `ReturnProps` type:

```
interface ReturnProps {
  [index: number]: Record<string, unknown>;
  [index: number]: (e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
}
```

You can't have two duplicate index signatures like that.

Since the first element in the returned array will be the Record, and the second will be the callback, use a tuple instead:

```
type ReturnProps = [
    Record<string, unknown>,
    (e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
]
```

You could even omit the `ReturnProps` entirely, and TS will still be able to infer the proper type:

```
const useForm = (initialValues: Record<string, unknown>) => {
```

(Letting TS infer types automatically when possible can really cut down on type noise that may distract from the main logic of your script.)

Comment: Thanks for that bro!